# Is 'by the bye' an acceptable variant of 'by the by'?

Tags: phrases, spelling

[This blog](https://writingexplained.org/idiom-dictionary/by-the-by#:%7E:text=This%20phrase%20can%20be%20written%20in%20two%20ways%3A%20by%20the%20by%20and%20by%20the%20bye.%20Both%20spellings%20mean%20the%20same%20thing%3B%20by%20the%20by%20is%20the%20more%20common%20variant.) says,

> This phrase can be written in two ways: by the by and **by the bye**. Both spellings mean the same thing; by the by is the more common variant.

Yet [this blog](https://grammarist.com/usage/by-and-by-by-the-by/#:%7E:text=Bye%20and%20bye%2C%C2%A0bye%20the%20bye%2C%20by%20the%20bye%2C%20etc.%20are%20misspellings.) says,

> Bye and bye, bye the bye, **by the bye**, etc. are misspellings.

So I'm confused.

Comment: I'm with 'both are fine' and so is Merriam-Webster. Many sources agree that _by the by_ is the original spelling, while _by the bye_ is now an accepted variant, so stick with _by the by_ to be absolutely safe from attack.

Comment: The question of "acceptable" is an interesting one in English.  There is no "Academy of the English Language" that sets official standards, so English is basically whatever English speakers think is acceptable.  I happen to think that "by the *bye*" is silly, but if enough people disagree...

Comment: I think *by **and** by* (*soon*, after a while) is a completely different usage from *by **the** bye* (*incidentally*; used to introduce a *related* topic). The "and" version [very rarely](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=by+and+by%2CBy+and+by%2Cby+and+bye%2CBy+and+bye%2Cbye+and+bye%2CBye+and+bye&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) includes the ***bye*** spelling....

Comment: ...but ***bye*** is [still common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=by+the+by%2CBy+the+by%2Cby+the+bye%2CBy+the+bye%2Cbye+the+bye%2CBye+the+bye&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) for the second occurrence in the "the" version.

Comment: Even though the full OED lists the second form under a heading **by the by**, I can't help but notice *almost all* of their usage citations spell it **by the bye**.

Comment: Bizarrely, the full OED has several separate listings for **by**, and *by the bye* turns up within "cited usages" for several of them. But the actual "subdefinition" specifically for **by the by** (spelled thusly) has definition 2c. ***by the by** is used parenthetically, with the omission of some phrase, such as ‘it may be remarked’. So **by the way**: see **way***. That one has 4 cited usages (most recent 1866), but only the first (1710) omits the final 'e' of the second occurrence....

Comment: ... ***By and by*** actually has its own main listing, but the spelling there is all over the place (I see at least 4 cited usages (going back to 1300) spelling that one ***bi and bi***. But all the recent ones seem to be ***by and by***.

Comment: @stangdon: In case it's not obvious, I think ***by and bye*** is silly. But I always write ***by the bye***, and until I've been looking into it just now, I've always assumed that anyone who didn't include the final 'e' in *that* version was just "uneducated". I think the evidence is that my orthography still holds sway, but "simplification" is definitely an ongoing process here.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yeah, **by and bye** is definitely silly.  I guess it's hard to say what is "correct" in *by the by(e)*, because the individual words don't each have a very obvious meaning.  Apparently the second *by* means "a secondary issue" (as in *by-way*), but I never knew that before I went to look it up.

Comment: 60 years ago my dad often used to take us out for a Sunday afternoon drive (bit of a weird concept today, but we liked it back then). I recall one of my siblings once said *How come there are so many villages called "Laybee"?* (her pronunciation for the sign saying [Lay-by.](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/lay-by)) Which I've *never* seen spelt with an 'e' until a couple of minutes ago! Bizarrely, that sister now lives in a North Lincolnshire village called ***Aby***, and there are a dozen villages within 10 miles with *very* similar names!

Comment: (Me, I just take that as further evidence we live in a simulation that's running short of computing power, so everything has to get "re-used" :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Lots of -by places in Eastern England. Viking.

Comment: Villages called ***Swaby*** and ***Alby*** are within walking distance of ***Aby***, where my sister lives.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - my dad was born not far from Sileby, and you can walk to Rearsby, Hoby, Brooksby, Frisby on the Wreake, Ashfordby, Kirby Bellars, Barsby, Gaddesby, Eye Kettleby, Ashby Folville, and Great Dalby. Leicestershire, once part of the Danelaw. Make it a bus ride and you can have dozens, I think.

Comment: __Weird__. I would've expected part of the disagreement here to be regional dialects. Rather odd that [Grammarist turns out to be Canadian](https://grammarist.com/about/) and [WritingExplained turns out to be by a guy in Grand Rapids, Michigan](https://www.linkedin.com/in/jordan-conrad-396789a9), basically Canuckistan South.

Comment: @lly: Regional dialects would very rarely have anything to do with *orthography*, so you shouldn't expect spelling variation at any lower level than country. Newspapers and publishing houses tend to be national rather than international, so that's the level at which preferred spelling becomes apparent, but we don't normally contrast AmE and BrE as two "dialects". The main issue is probably that Webster encouraged much spelling reform in C19 US, in which context ***by the bye*** was a sitting duck.

Comment: Regional doesn't solely mean subnational, and the AmE and BrE thing is a strawman. People discussing them generally mean GA vs RP, which of course are two "dialects". Not that I mentioned any of the four in this comment.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sometimes a new spelling becomes as common as the traditional spelling.  If that is the case then the new spelling can be called a variant or an alternative spelling.

This might be because the alternate spelling seems appropriate.  There is a type of carnivorous insect called a "[praying mantis](https://www.nationalgeographic.com/animals/invertebrates/facts/praying-mantis)" (from how they hold their forearms as if in prayer) but as they prey on other insects they are often called "[preying mantis](http://artemis.austincollege.edu/acad/bio/sgoldsmith/skg_ebe/preying_mantis.htm)". It's wrong, but it quite common.  These misspellings are sometimes called "eggcorns" (from a misspelling of acorn).

Sometimes the traditional spelling is forgotten.  There was a word in English that means money that you owe, it was spelled "det".  But some people thought it should have a "b" like the Latin word "debit", so they misspelled the word "debt".  Over time the new spelling completely took over, so the tradition spelling is now considered to be the mistake.

As for "by the by", which means "incidentally",  there is no doubt that "by the by" is the traditional spelling and is generally considered correct.  On the other hand "by the bye" is an eggcorn. It's quite common, many people will be happy to accept this spelling, but some people will consider it to be wrong.

As a learner, take the safe option and spell it "by the by".

"By and by" is a separate idiom with a different meaning ("before long").  Again the traditional spelling is "by".  Neither "by and by" nor "by the by" are related to "bye" (meaning farewell) or "bye" (a point scored without a hit in cricket, except that "bye" in this sense also was originally just a variant spelling of "by")

The etymology of these phrases can be found at [etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=by&utm_source=extension_submit). "By the by" comes from a mostly obsolete sense of by, meaning "not main" You still find this sense in the word "byway". Whereas "by and by" comes from a phrase originally meaning "the next and the next" from the sense of "by" indicating "the next in line" and so "soon".

Comment: You didn't mention *by **and** by* - for which the orthographic variations over tme (and probably the etymology; I haven't checked) are *very* different.

Comment: If this is going to be the lead answer, it's worth someone taking the time -- @FumbleFingers ? -- and adding in the general situation about "by and by*e*" under that spelling. Right now it looks like the situation from before carries over but from the comments above I don't think that's the case.

Comment: Both "by the by" and "by and by" are idioms formed with the prepostion "by".  But they date back to a time when English spelling was not standardized, and the word "by" wasn't always spelled the same. But since the word in all cases is "by" that spelling is uncontroversial.  A learner should be confident that "by and by" and "by the by" are both correct (and "safe") whereas "by the bye" or "by and bye" are sometimes considered incorrect, and could (for example) lose marks in a test.

Comment: @JamesK: I'm okay with saying ***by and bye*** is "incorrect", but anyone who thinks ***by the bye*** is in the same class is probably a bit of a pedant. Obviously anyone who uses both spellings in the same collocation *knows what they're doing* (it's hardly something you could do by accident, or that you wouldn't expect to be *noticed*). Apparently today (especially in AmE) you're pretty safe using ***by*** everywhere, but learners shouldn't be given the impression they know English "better" than those native Anglophones who still prefer ***by the bye***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Where do you draw the line though? I'm thinking of "could care less" which is the literal opposite of caring as little as possible, yet that's becoming more and more common. Also, I think you got "by the by" and "by the bye" switched around. "by" is the original as the etymonline page linked shows.

Answer (score 2):

It's worth noting that there are two significantly different idioms here. The much older one is *by **and** by* (meaning ***soon, after a [little] while***), which is [very rarely spelt with any **e**'s...](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=but%20by%20and%20by%2Cbut%20by%20and%20bye&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=10)

[image]

The other idiom is *by **the** bye* (meaning ***by the way, incidentally***), where as [this chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=but%20by%20the%20by%2Cbut%20by%20the%20bye%2Cbut%20bye%20the%20bye&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=10) shows, that extra 'e' is still present in over a third of all written instances.

[image]

It's important to note that ***bye the bye*** doesn't occur often enough to show on the chart. That in itself is clear evidence that a *lot* of careful writers over the centuries have thought of them as different words with different spellings. So although I can't disagree with the general principle "Simplest is Best" (so just forget about ***bye***), you should be aware that at least *some* people will still think it should be ***bye*** after ***the***.

---

I won't waste my time (or yours) digging into the etymology (but I bet the two usages have different backgrounds). You won't be alone if you stick to ***by*** throughout, and it's obvious which direction the orthographic trend is heading. Trotting out history lessons isn't necessarily a good way to learn *current* English.

Comment: __I'd__ like the etymology if someone has time to edit this reply.

Comment: Also curious how badly the ngram skews one way or the other between the US and UK corp(ora|uses). It seems like the UK posters above have all grown up with _by the bye_ their entire lives but it seems like it must be less common across the pond.

Comment: You can just click the link before the second chart and change the corpus to AmE or BrE. The former has always favoured ***by*** throughout, but it's approximately the same story everywhere. For your other point, I'd have thought most online dictionaries give etymologies, but it's not directly relevant to OP's question about *current* "acceptability".

Comment: Yep, I and everyone else here could always google everything on our own. The point of comments is to mention how to improve answers _here_, which I have done. No, there's no obligation to act on it.

Answer (score -3):

1. by the by is the "original" and correct, and meaningful, spelling. You can trivially google this and the meaning.
2. "by the bye" is completely pointless. (As would be, for example, "buy the by" or "bouy the buy" or such.)

Eggcorns are ***reasonable and have a point***.

(As in the superb historical example given by James, "debt," or say "tenderhooks".)

"by the bye" is just "silly wrong", a sort of tortured folk etymology, say.

Comment: -1 This site is for answers based in fact, backed by reliable sources. The answer space here is not for representing strong personal opinion as an answer, nor for ranting about the site and its users, nor for commenting on other answers. Some of that may have merit in [Meta], but not here.